# $\int \cos(w_1t)\cos(w_2t)\,dt$ integral

Tags: integration

Could you please give me a hint about how to proceed to resolve this integral? I've tried several times starting from different trigonometric rules but I don't find the answer :(

$$\int \cos(w_1t)\cos(w_2t)\,dt$$

with: $$w_2=w_1 + \Delta w$$

This is the answer it should give:
[image]

(Forget the part before the integral.)

Thank you so much in advance for your help!!
Kind regards.

Comment: Does this help? $$\cos(w_1t)\cos(w_2t)=\frac{1}{2}(\cos((w_1-w_2)t)+\cos((w_1+w_2)t))$$

Comment: agggg I was just reading again the cheatsheet about the trigonometric identities and that is the answer to my question :facepalm:

Thank you so much for the fast help!!

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html